# Android text-size programmatically too big

Tags: android, textview

I have two szenarios:

First:

```
 textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.defaultTextSize));
```

Second in xml:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/defaultTextSize"
```

in values/dimen.xml i have declared defaultTextSize with 20sp

In my first case the text is much bigger (and different in some screenresulutions) than in my second case. Why?
Have I done a mistake?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`setTextSize()` takes unit as pixel

Use this

```
public float pixelsToSp(float px) 
{
    float scaledDensity = _context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return px/scaledDensity;
}

textView.setTextSize(pixelsToSp(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.defaultTextSize)));
```

or

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.defaultTextSize))
```

Comment: Absolutely no clue why, but the second recommendation does not work on my GalaxyS4. Oi Vey Android...but solution 1 worked, so thanks.

Comment: @Kufuma it doesn't work because it's wrong: should be `COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` instead of `COMPLEX_UNIT_SP`. See also Blackbelt's answer in this page.

Answer (score 17):

The implementation of `setTextSize(float size)`

```
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
}
```

What is happening, in your case, is that you are scaling the value you provided to `setTextSize`, since `getDimension` returns the dimension multiplied by the metric. Try with

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.defaultTextSize));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the size in dimens.xml

```
   <dimen name="text_medium">18sp</dimen>
```

Then, use the following to set the size wherever you want

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_medium));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
   textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.defaultTextSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView uses Resources.getDimensionPixelSize method, not Resources.getDimension for textSize.